# How does COM call other another component written in another language?

Tags: c#, .net, com

How does COM call other another component written in another language ? 
if i have component written in c# and another component written in c++ 
How can c# component  call c++ component ? 
sorry for my bad english

i don't want the code .. i wanted the idea of calling com components each other

Comment: you didn't understand me i don't want the code .. i wanted the idea of calling com components each other

Comment: COM defines an ABI, all COM components are expected to follow it regardless of the language used. In the case of C# (or any other .NET language) the runtime will generate [wrappers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxz80y2(v=vs.110).aspx) to marshal between native COM objects and the managed world.

Comment: i read in a book that " Com did enable components to instantiate other components and call methods or properties against them, without worrying about the language in which the respective components were written " is that right ?

Comment: What is so surprising?  On Linux, Windos, OS X, you can run programs written in any language as long as they conform to the binary standard required by the platform.

In the case of COM, there is a binary standard starting with IUnknown.  As long as programs or libraries conform to the binary standard, they can call on one another.

Comment: Thank you for explain it for me ..